# Bytecode features not available in the Java language

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

Are there currently (Java 6) things you can do in Java bytecode that you can't do from within the Java language?

I know both are Turing complete, so read "can do" as "can do significantly faster/better, or just in a different way".

I'm thinking of extra bytecodes like `invokedynamic`, which can't be generated using Java, except that specific one is for a future version.

Comment: Define "things". In the end, the Java language and Java bytecode are both Turing complete...

Comment: Is the real question; is there any advantage programming in byte code e.g. using Jasmin, instead of Java?

Comment: Like `rol` in assembler, which you can't write in C++.

Comment: It's a very poor optimizing compiler that can't compile `(x<<n)|(x>>(32-n))` to a `rol` instruction.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

As far as I know there are no major features in the bytecodes supported by Java 6 that are not also accessible from Java source code. The main reason for this is obviously that the Java bytecode was designed with the Java language in mind.

There are some features that are not produced by modern Java compilers, however:

- The [`ACC_SUPER` flag](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#13484):

  This is a flag that can be set on a class and specifies how a specific corner case of the `invokespecial` bytecode is handled for this class. It is set by all modern Java compilers (where "modern" is >= Java 1.1, if I remember correctly) and only ancient Java compilers produced class files where this was un-set. This flag exists only for backwards-compatibility reasons. Note that starting with Java 7u51, ACC_SUPER is ignored completely due to security reasons.
- The `jsr`/`ret` bytecodes.

  These bytecodes  were used to implement sub-routines (mostly for implementing `finally` blocks). They are [no longer produced since Java 6](http://cliffhacks.blogspot.com/2008/02/java-6-tryfinally-compilation-without.html). The reason for their deprecation is that they complicate static verification a lot for no great gain (i.e. code that uses can almost always be re-implemented with normal jumps with very little overhead).
- Having two methods in a class that only differ in return type.

  The Java language specification does not allow two methods in the same class when they differ *only* in their return type (i.e. same name, same argument list, ...). The JVM specification however, has no such restriction, so a class file *can* contain two such methods, there's just no way to produce such a class file using the normal Java compiler. There's a nice example/explanation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110014/is-this-valid-java/3110204#3110204).

Comment: I could add another answer, but we might as well make yours the canonical answer. You may want to mention that a method's signature in bytecode *includes the return type*. That is, you can have two methods with exactly the same parameter types, but different return types. See this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110014/is-this-valid-java/3110204#3110204

Comment: @Adam: Thanks, I've added it and made this CW.

Comment: You can have class, method and field names with just about any character. I worked on one project where the "fields" had spaces and hyphens in their names. :P

Comment: Oh boy, my definition of "major features" is becoming more and more narrow ;-)

Comment: @Peter: I've heard of that as well and I was trying to find the relevant places in the JVM spec and JLS, in order to be able to quote them in my answer, but can't find any. Do you know of some place where this is specified/documented/blogged/...?

Comment: I came across something once... I believe its `/` and `;` you can't have in a byte code name. I have tried space, tab and newline and they work. Class names cannot have characters the filesystem won't allow, but it might be possible to construct a JAR with extra-special characters. That would make it especially hard to decompile.

Comment: @Peter: Speaking of file system characters, I ran into an obfuscator that had renamed a class to `a` and another to `A` inside the JAR file. It took me about half an hour of unzipping **on a Windows machine** before I realized where the missing classes were. :)

Comment: @JoachimSauer: paraphrased JVM spec, page 75: class names, methods, fields, and local variables can contain *any* character except `'.'`, `';'`, `'['`, or `'/'`. Method names are the same, but they also can't contain `'<'` or `'>'`. (With the notable exceptions of `<init>` and `<clinit>` for instance and static constructors.) I should point out that if you are following the specification strictly, the class names are actually much more constrained, but the constraints are not enforced.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: also, an undocumented addition of my own: the java language includes the `"throws ex1, ex2, ..., exn"` as part of the method signatures; you can't add exception throwing clauses to overridden methods. BUT, the JVM couldn't care less. So only `final` methods are truly guaranteed by the JVM to be exception-free - aside from `RuntimeException`s and `Error`s, of course. So much for checked exception handling :D

Comment: @aboveyou00: Even final methods provide no guaranty, as on bytecode level they may throw any exception regardless of whether they declared its type or not.

Answer (score 415):

After working with Java byte code for quite a while and doing some additional research on this matter, here is a summary of my findings:

**Execute code in a constructor before calling a super constructor or auxiliary constructor**

In the Java programming language (JPL), a constructor's first statement must be an invocation of a super constructor or another constructor of the same class. This is not true for Java byte code (JBC). Within byte code, it is absolutely legitimate to execute any code before a constructor, as long as:

- Another compatible constructor is called at some time after this code block.
- This call is not within a conditional statement.
- Before this constructor call, no field of the constructed instance is read and none of its methods is invoked. This implies the next item.

**Set instance fields before calling a super constructor or auxiliary constructor**

As mentioned before, it is perfectly legal to set a field value of an instance before calling another constructor. There even exists a legacy hack which makes it able to exploit this "feature" in Java versions before 6:

```
class Foo {
  public String s;
  public Foo() {
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  public Bar() {
    this(s = "Hello World!");
  }
  private Bar(String helper) {
    super();
  }
}
```

This way, a field could be set before the super constructor is invoked which is however not longer possible. In JBC, this behavior can still be implemented.

**Branch a super constructor call**

In Java, it is not possible to define a constructor call like

```
class Foo {
  Foo() { }
  Foo(Void v) { }
}

class Bar() {
  if(System.currentTimeMillis() % 2 == 0) {
    super();
  } else {
    super(null);
  }
}
```

<s>Until Java 7u23, the HotSpot VM's verifier did however miss this check which is why it was possible. This was used by several code generation tools as a sort of a hack but it is not longer legal to implement a class like this.</s>

The latter was merely a bug in this compiler version. In newer compiler versions, this is again possible.

**Define a class without any constructor**

The Java compiler will always implement at least one constructor for any class. In Java byte code, this is not required. This allows the creation of classes that cannot be constructed even when using reflection. However, using `sun.misc.Unsafe` still allows for the creation of such instances.

**Define methods with identical signature but with different return type**

In the JPL, a method is identified as unique by its name and its raw parameter types. In JBC, the raw return type is additionally considered.

**Define fields that do not differ by name but only by type**

A class file can contain several fields of the same name as long as they declare a different field type. The JVM always refers to a field as a tuple of name and type.

**Throw undeclared checked exceptions without catching them**

The Java runtime and the Java byte code are not aware of the concept of checked exceptions. It is only the Java compiler that verifies that checked exceptions are always either caught or declared if they are thrown.

**Use dynamic method invocation outside of lambda expressions**

The so-called [dynamic method invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6638735/1237575) can be used for anything, not only for Java's lambda expressions. Using this feature allows for example to switch out execution logic at runtime. Many dynamic programming languages that boil down to JBC [improved their performance](http://groovy.codehaus.org/InvokeDynamic+support) by using this instruction. In Java byte code, you could also emulate lambda expressions in Java 7 where the compiler did not yet allow for any use of dynamic method invocation while the JVM already understood the instruction.

**Use identifiers that are not normally considered legal**

Ever fancied using spaces and a line break in your method's name? Create your own JBC and good luck for code review. The only illegal characters for identifiers are `.`, `;`, `[` and  `/`. Additionally, methods that are not named `<init>` or `<clinit>` cannot contain `<` and `>`.

**Reassign `final` parameters or the `this` reference**

`final` parameters do not exist in JBC and can consequently be reassigned. Any parameter, including the `this` reference is only stored in a simple array within the JVM what allows to reassign the `this` reference at index `0` within a single method frame.

**Reassign `final` fields**

As long as a final field is assigned within a constructor, it is legal to reassign this value or even not assign a value at all. Therefore, the following two constructors are legal:

```
class Foo {
  final int bar;
  Foo() { } // bar == 0
  Foo(Void v) { // bar == 2
    bar = 1;
    bar = 2;
  }
}
```

For `static final` fields, it is even allowed to reassign the fields outside of 
the class initializer.

**Treat constructors and the class initializer as if they were methods**

This is more of a *conceptional feature* but constructors are not treated any differently within JBC than normal methods. It is only the JVM's verifier that assures that constructors call another legal constructor. Other than that, it is merely a Java naming convention that constructors must be called `<init>` and that the class initializer is called `<clinit>`. Besides this difference, the representation of methods and constructors is identical. As Holger pointed out in a comment, you can even define constructors with return types other than `void` or a class initializer with arguments, even though it is not possible to call these methods.

**Create asymmetric records***.

When creating a record

```
record Foo(Object bar) { }
```

javac will generate a class file with a single field named `bar`, an accessor method named `bar()` and a constructor taking a single `Object`. Additionally, a record attribute for `bar` is added. By manually generating a record, it is possible to create, a different constructor shape, to skip the field and to implement the accessor differently. At the same time, it is still possible to make the reflection API believe that the class represents an actual record.

**Call any super method (until Java 1.1)**

However, this is only possible for Java versions 1 and 1.1. In JBC, methods are always dispatched on an explicit target type. This means that for

```
class Foo {
  void baz() { System.out.println("Foo"); }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  @Override
  void baz() { System.out.println("Bar"); }
}

class Qux extends Bar {
  @Override
  void baz() { System.out.println("Qux"); }
}
```

it was possible to implement `Qux#baz` to invoke `Foo#baz` while jumping over `Bar#baz`. While it is still possible to define an explicit invocation to call another super method implementation than that of the direct super class, this does no longer have any effect in Java versions after 1.1. In Java 1.1, this behavior was controlled by setting the `ACC_SUPER` flag which would enable the same behavior that only calls the direct super class's implementation.

**Define a non-virtual call of a method that is declared in the same class**

In Java, it is not possible to define a class

```
class Foo {
  void foo() {
    bar();
  }
  void bar() { }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  @Override void bar() {
    throw new RuntimeException();
  }
}
```

The above code will always result in a `RuntimeException` when `foo` is invoked on an instance of `Bar`. It is not possible to define the `Foo::foo` method to invoke *its own* `bar` method which is defined in `Foo`. As `bar` is a non-private instance method, the call is always virtual. With byte code, one can however define the invocation to use the `INVOKESPECIAL` opcode which directly links the `bar` method call in `Foo::foo` to `Foo`'s version. This opcode is normally used to implement super method invocations but you can reuse the opcode to implement the described behavior.

**Fine-grain type annotations**

In Java, annotations are applied according to their `@Target` that the annotations declares. Using byte code manipulation, it is possible to define annotations independently of this control. Also, it is for example possible to annotate a parameter type without annotating the parameter even if the `@Target` annotation applies to both elements.

**Define any attribute for a type or its members**

Within the Java language, it is only possible to define annotations for fields, methods or classes. In JBC, you can basically embed any information into the Java classes. In order to make use of this information, you can however no longer rely on the Java class loading mechanism but you need to extract the meta information by yourself.

**Overflow and implicitly assign `byte`, `short`, `char` and `boolean` values**

The latter primitive types are not normally known in JBC but are only defined for array types or for field and method descriptors. Within byte code instructions, all of the named types take the space 32 bit which allows to represent them as `int`. Officially, only the `int`, `float`, `long` and `double` types exist within byte code which all need explicit conversion by the rule of the JVM's verifier.

**Not release a monitor**

A `synchronized` block is actually made up of two statements, one to acquire and one to release a monitor. In JBC, you can acquire one without releasing it.

*Note*: In recent implementations of HotSpot, this instead leads to an `IllegalMonitorStateException` at the end of a method or to an implicit release if the method is terminated by an exception itself.

**Add more than one `return` statement to a type initializer**

In Java, even a trivial type initializer such as

```
class Foo {
  static {
    return;
  }
}
```

is illegal. In byte code, the type initializer is treated just as any other method, i.e. return statements can be defined anywhere.

**Create irreducible loops**

The Java compiler converts loops to goto statements in Java byte code. Such statements can be used to create irreducible loops, which the Java compiler never does.

**Define a recursive catch block**

In Java byte code, you can define a block:

```
try {
  throw new Exception();
} catch (Exception e) {
  <goto on exception>
  throw Exception();
}
```

A similar statement is created implicitly when using a `synchronized` block in Java where any exception while releasing a monitor returns to the instruction for releasing this monitor. Normally, no exception should occur on such an instruction but if it would (e.g. the deprecated `ThreadDeath`), the monitor would still be released.

**Call any default method**

The Java compiler requires several conditions to be fulfilled in order to allow a default method's invocation:

1. The method must be the most specific one (must not be overridden by a sub interface that is implemented by **any** type, including super types).
2. The default method's interface type must be implemented directly by the class that is calling the default method. However, if interface `B` extends interface `A` but does not override a method in `A`, the method can still be invoked.

For Java byte code, only the second condition counts. The first one is however irrelevant.

**Invoke a super method on an instance that is not `this`**

The Java compiler only allows to invoke a super (or interface default) method on instances of `this`. In byte code, it is however also possible to invoke the super method on an instance of the same type similar to the following:

```
class Foo {
  void m(Foo f) {
    f.super.toString(); // calls Object::toString
  }
  public String toString() {
    return "foo";
  }
}
```

**Access synthetic members**

In Java byte code, it is possible to access synthetic members directly. For example, consider how in the following example the outer instance of another `Bar` instance is accessed:

```
class Foo {
  class Bar { 
    void bar(Bar bar) {
      Foo foo = bar.Foo.this;
    }
  }
}
```

This is generally true for any synthetic field, class or method.

**Define out-of-sync generic type information**

While the Java runtime does not process generic types (after the Java compiler applies type erasure), this information is still attcheched to a compiled class as meta information and made accessible via the reflection API.

The verifier does not check the consistency of these meta data `String`-encoded values. It is therefore possible to define information on generic types that does not match the erasure. As a concequence, the following assertings can be true:

```
Method method = ...
assertTrue(method.getParameterTypes() != method.getGenericParameterTypes());

Field field = ...
assertTrue(field.getFieldType() == String.class);
assertTrue(field.getGenericFieldType() == Integer.class);
```

Also, the signature can be defined as invalid such that a runtime exception is thrown. This exception is thrown when the information is accessed for the first time as it is evaluated lazily. (Similar to annotation values with an error.)

**Append parameter meta information only for certain methods**

The Java compiler allows for embedding parameter name and modifier information when compiling a class with the `parameter` flag enabled. In the Java class file format, this information is however stored per-method what makes it possible to only embed such method information for certain methods.

**Mess things up and hard-crash your JVM**

As an example, in Java byte code, you can define to invoke any method on any type. Usually, the verifier will complain if a type does not known of such a method. However, if you invoke an unknown method on an array, I found a bug in some JVM version where the verifier will miss this and your JVM will finish off once the instruction is invoked. This is hardly a feature though, but it is technically something that is not possible with *javac* compiled Java. Java has some sort of double validation. The first validation is applied by the Java compiler, the second one by the JVM when a class is loaded. By skipping the compiler, you might find a weak spot in the verifier's validation. This is rather a general statement than a feature, though.

**Annotate a constructor's receiver type when there is no outer class**

Since Java 8, non-static methods and constructors of inner classes can declare a receiver type and annotate these types. Constructors of top-level classes cannot annotate their receiver type as they most not declare one.

```
class Foo {
  class Bar {
    Bar(@TypeAnnotation Foo Foo.this) { }
  }
  Foo() { } // Must not declare a receiver type
}
```

Since `Foo.class.getDeclaredConstructor().getAnnotatedReceiverType()` does however return an `AnnotatedType` representing `Foo`, it is possible to include type annotations for `Foo`'s constructor directly in the class file where these annotations are later read by the reflection API.

**Use unused / legacy byte code instructions**

Since others named it, I will include it as well. Java was formerly making use of subroutines by the `JSR` and `RET` statements. JBC even knew its own type of a return address for this purpose. However, the use of subroutines did overcomplicate static code analysis which is why these instructions are not longer used. Instead, the Java compiler will duplicate code it compiles. However, this basically creates identical logic which is why I do not really consider it to achieve something different. Similarly, you could for example add the `NOOP` byte code instruction which is not used by the Java compiler either but this would not really allow you to achieve something new either. As pointed out in the context, these mentioned "feature instructions" are now removed from the set of legal opcodes which does render them even less of a feature.

Comment: Regarding method names, you can have more than one `<clinit>` method by defining methods with the name `<clinit>` but accepting parameters or having a non-`void` return type. But these methods are not very useful, the JVM will ignore them and the byte code can’t invoke them. The only use would be to confuse readers.

Comment: I just discovered, that Oracle’s JVM detects an unreleased monitor at method exit and throws an `IllegalMonitorStateException` if you omitted the `monitorexit` instruction. And in case of an exceptional method exit that failed to do a `monitorexit`, it resets the monitor silently.

Comment: @Holger - did not know that, I know that this was possible in earlier JVMs at least, JRockit even has its own handler for this kind of implementation. I'll update the entry.

Comment: Well, the JVM specification does not mandate such a behavior. I just discovered it because I tried to create a dangling intrinsic lock using such non-standard byte code.

Comment: Ok, [I found the relevant spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11.10): “*Structured locking* is the situation when, during a method invocation, every exit on a given monitor matches a preceding entry on that monitor. Since there is no assurance that all code submitted to the Java Virtual Machine will perform structured locking, implementations of the Java Virtual Machine are permitted but not required to enforce both of the following two rules guaranteeing structured locking. …”

Comment: Regarding MONITORENTER/EXIT - one use is to not always lock. It's sort of available without bytecode editing but you must duplicate code.

Example here: https://gist.github.com/nallar/c86d0b45f782c660bff8

Real world example: https://github.com/nallar/TickThreading/blob/MC152/src/common/nallar/tickthreading/minecraft/tickregion/TileEntityTickRegion.java#L36

If you end up doing this you should probably refactor/find an alternate way, or just use Lock objects - overhead from doing that is small.
I was later able to refactor the shown code to avoid the need for MONITORENTER/EXIT.

Comment: Wow. What a great answer. Are they anymore things you can do in Java 1.7 and 1.8?

Comment: I noticed the MethodType javadoc says it can be loaded with the ldc instruction, but I was not able to find Java syntax for it.  Does anyone know if this is somehow possible?

Comment: No, not explicitly. But whenever you implement a lambda expression, the arguments to the bootsrap method are stored in the constant pool which includes method types.

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/programmingcirclejerk/comments/330d56/i_program_in_java_bytecode_ama/ "Sometimes when I'm writing a really great program, I think "if only I could Set instance fields before calling a super constructor or auxiliary constructor then this program would be 10X webscale."" funny indeed. It's not complicated until you make it...

Comment: Another JVM restriction on super-constructor calls I think is that the call to a constructor must not be guarded by a `catch`; forbidding such constructs entirely is probably easier than trying to bullet-proof a construct where a constructor call could act upon an exception thrown in a super-constructor but would still be required to pass that exception onto its caller.  Too bad, since it means it's almost impossible to have a constructor allocate a resource and give it to the parent without the resource leaking if the parent constructor throws.

Comment: "Call a method with this set to null" - presumably this is only possible with INVOKESPECIAL and INVOKEDYNAMIC? I'd expect INVOKEVIRTUAL and INVOKEINTERFACE to fail, since it's unclear which method to invoke.

Comment: @James_pic You are right, the resolution of the method would fail and a `NullPointerException` would be thrown the same way as when calling a method on a null reference.

Comment: Note that `ACC_SUPER` was effectively removed in Java 8 for security reasons. Also, you are still allowed to branch on super constructor calls. The thing about 7u23 was a bug in the JVM.

Comment: While the `ACC_SUPER` flag was removed from Oracle's VM implementation, javac still adds the flag. As far as I Also, Android's verifier even checks that the flag is present.

Comment: It’s a bit misleading to say that the `ACC_SUPER` was removed (and apparently, exactly that creates confusion). The point is that the *absence* of the flag allowed a now-unsupported behavior and thus, the flag has not been removed, instead, every class is now treated as if the flag is present, regardless of whether it actually is. And conforming compilers still produce class files with that flag.

Comment: *"Mess things up and hard-crash your JVM"* - If you can do that with (just) bytecodes, then that is JVM bug or a JVM Spec bug.

Comment: You can always redefine system classes on the bootstrap loader where this is not to hard to get working.

Comment: @supercat you can guard super constructor calls on the bytecode level. Due to the undefined state of the instance (may be initialized or not), the exception handler is not allowed to return normally, but it may do resource cleanup, followed by re-throwing the exception, as you intend. Throwing another exception or looping forever is also allowed.

Comment: @Holger: Interesting.  I don't remember where I read about the restrictions, but I thought the language was upholding a bytecode-based restriction.  If the bytecode would be able to handle an exception handler under the constraints you gave, it seems unfortunate that the language can't, since there's really no way to achieve clean resource semantics without it.

Comment: @supercat yeah, I know that wish is reoccurring. I put a [self contained example on Ideone](https://ideone.com/ucdlTa) generating a subclass which catches exceptions thrown by the superclass constructor to `close()` the resource before re-throwing (including `addSuppressed` logic). It works. So it’s just the language which doesn’t support this.

Comment: @Holger: That's a real shame, since it means robust resource management is essentially impossible in Java.  Finalizers have always been a broken mechanism, and while try-with-resources fixed a lot, there's still a major hole when it comes to subclass construction.

Comment: The switch bytecode instructions can jump backward, so you can use them to create a loop. The fancy thing about the branch structure is that [the specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11.1-400) mentions explicitly that [Duff’s device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) does not work in the Java language, but on the bytecode level, we could not only construct such code, we can even let the switch instruction implement the loop.

Answer (score 16):

Here are some features that can be done in Java bytecode but not in Java source code:

- **Throwing a checked exception from a method without declaring that the method throws it.** The checked and unchecked exceptions are a thing which is checked only by the Java compiler, not the JVM. Because of this for example Scala can throw checked exceptions from methods without declaring them. Though with Java generics there is a workaround called [sneaky throw](http://blog.jayway.com/2010/01/29/sneaky-throw/).
- **Having two methods in a class that only differ in return type,** as already mentioned in [Joachim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827363/bytecode-features-not-available-in-the-java-language/6827552#6827552): The Java language specification does not allow two methods in the same class when they differ *only* in their return type (i.e. same name, same argument list, ...). The JVM specification however, has no such restriction, so a class file *can* contain two such methods, there's just no way to produce such a class file using the normal Java compiler. There's a nice example/explanation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110014/is-this-valid-java/3110204#3110204).

Comment: Note that there **is** a way to do the first thing in Java. It's sometimes called a [sneaky throw](http://blog.jayway.com/2010/01/29/sneaky-throw/).

Comment: Now that's sneaky! :D Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I think you can also use `Thread.stop(Throwable)` for a sneaky throw. I assume the one already linked is faster though.

Comment: You can’t create an instance without calling a constructor in Java bytecode. The verifier will reject any code which tries to use an uninitialized instance. The object deserialization implementation uses native code helpers for creating instances without constructor calling.

Comment: For a class Foo extending Object, you could not instantiate Foo by calling a constructor that is declared in Object. The verifier would refuse it. You could create such a constructor using Java's ReflectionFactory but this hardly is a byte code feature but realized by Jni. Your answer is wrong and Holger is correct.

Comment: Regarding the controversial ability to skip calling a constructor, I was able to reproduce it on 32-bit jdk1.6.0_10, but not on other versions that I tried. Seems that it was a HotSpot bug. Here's the code: https://github.com/orfjackal/misc-tools/blob/db6c64d9dbe62b5afbf09e3516918ff5cbd5bc42/src/main/java/net/orfjackal/experimental/ConstructorSkipping.java

Answer (score 9):

- `GOTO` can be used with labels to create your own control structures (other than `for` `while` etc)
- You can override the `this` local variable inside a method
- Combining both of these you can create create tail call optimised bytecode (I do this in [JCompilo](http://code.google.com/p/jcompilo/))

As a related point you can get parameter name for methods if compiled with debug ([Paranamer does this by reading the bytecode](http://paranamer.codehaus.org/)

Comment: How do you `override` the this local variable?

Comment: @Michael overriding is a too strong word. On the bytecode level, all local variables are accessed by a numerical index and there is no difference between writing to an existing variable or initializing a new variable (with a disjunct scope), in either case, it’s just a write to a local variable. The `this` variable has index zero, but besides being pre-initialized with the `this` reference when entering an instance method, it’s just a local variable. So you can write a different value to it, which can act like ending `this`’ scope or changing the `this` variable, depending on how you use it.

Comment: I see! So really it is that `this` can be reassigned? I think it was just the word override which had me wondering what it meant exactly.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe section 7A in [this document](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~daw/joe-e/spec-20090918.pdf) is of interest, although it's about bytecode **pitfalls** rather than bytecode **features**.

Comment: Interesting read, but it doesn't look like one would *want* to (ab)use any of those things.

Answer (score 5):

In Java language the first statement in a constructor must be a call to the super class constructor. Bytecode does not have this limitation, instead the rule is that the super class constructor or another constructor in the same class must be called for the object before accessing the members. This should allow more freedom such as:

- Create an instance of another object, store it in a local variable (or stack) and pass it as a parameter to super class constructor while still keeping the reference in that variable for other use.
- Call different other constructors based on a condition. This should be possible: [How to call a different constructor conditionally in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236087/how-to-do-call-a-different-constructor-conditionally-in-java)

I have not tested these, so please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You can even set members of an instance before calling its superclass constructor. Reading fields or calling methods is however not possible before that.

Answer (score 4):

Something you can do with byte code, rather than plain Java code, is generate code which can loaded and run without a compiler.  Many systems have JRE rather than JDK and if you want to generate code dynamically it may be better, if not easier, to generate byte code instead of Java code has to be compiled before it can be used.

Comment: But then you're just skipping the compiler, not producing something that couldn't be produced using the compiler (if it were available).

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a bytecode optimizer when I was a I-Play, (it was designed to reduce the code size for J2ME applications). One feature I added was the ability to use inline bytecode (similar to inline assembly language in C++). I managed to reduce the size of a function that was part of a library method by using the DUP instruction, since I need the value twice. I also had zero byte instructions (if you are calling a method that takes a char and you want to pass an int, that you know does not need to be cast I added int2char(var) to replace char(var) and it would remove the i2c instruction to reduce the size of the code. I also made it do float a = 2.3; float b = 3.4; float c = a + b; and that would be converted to fixed point (faster, and also some J2ME did not support floating point).

Answer (score 4):

In Java, if you attempt to override a public method with a protected method (or any other reduction in access), you get an error: "attempting to assign weaker access privileges". If you do it with JVM bytecode, the verifier is fine with it, and you can call these methods via the parent class as if they were public.