# Conditional calling of a constructor

Tags: java, constructor, instanceof, constructor-overloading

I've a situation similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236087/how-to-call-a-different-constructor-conditionally-in-java).

What if I still want to call constructors conditionally? (Though they said creating separate classes is suggestible)

Requirement structure:

**Super class:**

```
 public class Super
    {
        public Super(DTO1 dto1Object){
               this.dto1Object = dto1Object;     
          }

        public Super(DTO2 dto2Object)){
               this.dto2Object = dto2Object;     
          }
    }
```

**Derived class:**

```
 public class Derived extends Super
    {
        public Derived(Object obj)
        {
           //some_condition to check if passed object obj is dto1Object                 
           //do something with dto1Object

           //some_condition to check if passed object is dto2Object                               
           //do something with dto2Object


        }
    }
```

How should I implement it?

**EDIT:**

Implemented it in this way based on the suggestion below:

**Super class:**

```
 public class Super
    {
        protected static DTO1 dto1Obj;
        protected static DTO2 dto2Obj;

        public Super(DTO1 dto1Object){
               this.dto1Object = dto1Object;     
          }

        public Super(DTO2 dto2Object)){
               this.dto2Object = dto2Object;     
          }
    }
```

**Derived class:**

```
    public class Derived extends Super
    {
        public Derived(DTO1 dto1Object){ super(dto1Object); }
        public Derived(DTO2 dto2Object){ super(dto2Object); }

        public static Derived create(Object obj) {

           if (obj.equals(dto1Obj) {
             return new Derived((DTO1) obj);
           }

           if (obj.equals(dto2Obj) {
             return new Derived((DTO2) obj);
           }

           // ...

          private String Function(String str){
            if(create(dto1Obj).equals(dto1Obj) { 
             //do something
            }
            else if(create(dto2Obj).equals(dto2Obj)){
             //do something else 
            }
            return str;
          }

        }
    }
```

**EDIT2:**

As per suggestion below, is this the correct way to use `instanceof`?

```
if (create(dto1Obj) instanceof DTO1) {
          //something
        }
        else if(create(dto2Obj) instanceof DTO2) {
          //something else
        }
```

Is shows the following error:

```
Incompatible conditional operand types Derived and DTO1
Incompatible conditional operand types Derived and DTO2
```

Comment: You can't in the constructor, because the `super(...)` has to be the first statement.

Comment: You can't, basically. Either you need to add a `Super(Object)` constructor, or create a static factory method in `Derived` and two separate private constructors.

Comment: yes. just use static factory - this is good practice according to the "Effective Java"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't in the constructor, because the `super(...)` has to be the first statement.

The only way I can think is to use a static factory method, and invoke class-specific overloads of the constructor:

```
public class Derived extends Super
{
    private Derived(DTO1 dto1Object){ super(dto1Object); }
    private Derived(DTO2 dto2Object){ super(dto2Object); }

    public static Derived create(Object obj) {
       //some_condition to check if passed object obj is dto1Object                 
       //do something with dto1Object
       if (someCondition) {
         return new Derived((DTO1) obj);
       }

       //some_condition to check if passed object is dto2Object                               
       //do something with dto2Object
       if (someOtherCondition) {
         return new Derived((DTO2) obj);
       }

       // ...?
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!
I've a quick question (may be a dumb one)

  
  Can I do this to check if obj is dto1Obj or dto2Obj?

if(create(dto1Obj).equals(dto1Obj)){ 
//do something
}
else {
//something else
}

Comment: You can use `instanceof`... But if that's the only check you're trying to do, why not just expose the constructors directly? Then the type is checked at compile time.

Comment: Do you mean the way I edited the post? (Can't post code here so I added as an edit in my question)