# You can access private variables in Java without getters from a class that's not an inner class

Tags: java, private

I have a clue of what serialVersionUID is for, and in as far as I don't I can look it up. But it can be a private variable that's not used inside the class. Is there some construct or so behind that? Are there other examples of private variables / methods that are not used inside the same class? Can I access private variables in Java without getters from a class that's not an inner class, like serialization does?

Comment: you can use [reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful)

Comment: downvoter please clarify.

Comment: No, please close. That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can access those values, and manipulate them via [Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful).
By this mechanism you can check fields and invoke methods.

Answer (score 1):

This field is being read by Java virtual machine which can do whatever it wants with your program including reading the private fields. Note that serialization-related methods like `writeObject` [can also be private](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/output.html#a861), but this is not a problem for JVM either.

You can also access private fields/methods via reflection or java.lang.invoke API (however `SecurityManager` may prevent you from doing this). In Oracle JDK/Open JDK there's also non-documented `sun.misc.Unsafe` API which allows you to do many *ughm* unsafe things including even reading the raw data from objects.

Answer (score 1):

Using `java.lang.reflect.Member.setAccessible(true)` will override any privacy at runtime (not that there is much – the JVM will happily access private fields or methods given their name, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827363/bytecode-features-not-available-in-the-java-language/23218472#23218472).