# How is this Java project using the language reserved words as identifiers?

Tags: java, keyword, identifier, decompiler, reserved

I have de-compiled a Java project using JD-GUI, and was surprised when I saw that all identifiers are using Java reserved keywords such as int do throw extends etc..

Here is a snippet of the project:

```
public class try extends Thread {
  private int do;
  
  private JSONArray if;
  
  private int for;
  
  private String int;
  
  private String new;
}
```

I read on a another post about using when UTF-16 encoding, some characters might look the same, but are actually different, so I switched the encoding using Notepad++ but that had no effect on the display.

I also tried using a few de-obfuscators from Github, but no success.

I know that it is not really using the reserved keywords, but i can't figure it out, so what's the trick here?

EDIT:

Here is the smallest class in the project:

```
package tech.iresponse.break;

import org.apache.commons.lang.exception.ExceptionUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class do {
  public static void do(Throwable paramThrowable) {
    Logger.getLogger("rootLogger").error(ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(paramThrowable));
  }
}


/* Location:              C:\Users\User\Desktop\app.jar!\tech\iresponse\break\do.class
 * Java compiler version: 8 (52.0)
 * JD-Core Version:       1.1.3
 */
```

And here is the hexdump:

```
00000000  ca fe ba be 00 00 00 34  01 19 08 00 9e 08 00 9f  |.......4........|
00000010  08 00 a0 08 00 a1 08 00  a2 08 00 a3 08 00 a4 08  |................|
00000020  00 bd 08 00 be 08 00 bf  08 00 c0 08 00 c1 08 00  |................|
00000030  c2 08 00 c3 08 00 c4 08  00 c5 08 00 c6 08 00 c9  |................|
00000040  08 00 ca 08 00 cb 08 00  cd 08 00 d3 08 00 d5 08  |................|
00000050  00 d6 08 00 e2 08 00 ec  08 00 ed 08 00 ff 08 01  |................|
00000060  00 08 01 01 08 01 04 08  01 05 08 01 12 08 01 15  |................|
00000070  07 00 ef 07 00 f0 07 00  f1 07 00 f2 07 00 f3 07  |................|
00000080  00 f4 07 00 f5 07 00 f6  07 00 f7 07 00 fa 07 00  |................|
00000090  fb 07 00 fc 07 01 06 07  01 07 07 01 08 07 01 09  |................|
000000a0  07 01 0a 07 01 0b 07 01  0c 07 01 0d 09 00 30 00  |..............0.|
000000b0  75 09 00 30 00 76 09 00  30 00 77 09 00 30 00 78  |u..0.v..0.w..0.x|
000000c0  09 00 30 00 80 09 00 30  00 81 09 00 30 00 89 09  |..0....0....0...|
000000d0  00 30 00 91 09 00 30 00  98 09 00 30 00 9d 09 00  |.0....0....0....|
000000e0  31 00 77 09 00 31 00 79  09 00 33 00 80 09 00 33  |1.w..1.y..3....3|
000000f0  00 86 09 00 33 00 8d 09  00 33 00 92 09 00 33 00  |....3....3....3.|
00000100  95 0a 00 24 00 9c 0a 00  25 00 82 0a 00 25 00 8a  |...$....%....%..|
00000110  0a 00 26 00 82 0a 00 27  00 6d 0a 00 27 00 71 0a  |..&....'.m..'.q.|
00000120  00 27 00 72 0a 00 27 00  73 0a 00 27 00 9a 0a 00  |.'.r..'.s..'....|
00000130  28 00 7a 0a 00 29 00 6d  0a 00 2b 00 6e 0a 00 2c  |(.z..).m..+.n..,|
00000140  00 97 0a 00 2d 00 87 0a  00 2d 00 93 0a 00 2e 00  |....-....-......|
00000150  88 0a 00 2f 00 7e 0a 00  30 00 6f 0a 00 30 00 74  |.../.~..0.o..0.t|
00000160  0a 00 30 00 7b 0a 00 30  00 8c 0a 00 30 00 99 0a  |..0.{..0....0...|
00000170  00 31 00 6f 0a 00 31 00  96 0a 00 32 00 70 0a 00  |.1.o..1....2.p..|
00000180  33 00 7c 0a 00 33 00 7d  0a 00 33 00 83 0a 00 33  |3.|..3.}..3....3|
00000190  00 8b 0a 00 33 00 8e 0a  00 33 00 94 0a 00 34 00  |....3....3....4.|
000001a0  9b 0a 00 35 00 7f 0a 00  36 00 84 0a 00 36 00 85  |...5....6....6..|
000001b0  0a 00 36 00 8f 0a 00 36  00 90 0c 00 c7 00 a9 0c  |..6....6........|
000001c0  00 c7 00 b0 0c 00 c7 00  b3 0c 00 c7 00 b7 0c 00  |................|
000001d0  d8 00 ac 0c 00 d8 00 b2  0c 00 d8 00 b6 0c 00 d9  |................|
000001e0  00 a5 0c 00 da 00 d0 0c  00 db 00 cf 0c 00 dc 00  |................|
000001f0  cf 0c 00 dd 00 d0 0c 00  de 00 cf 0c 00 df 00 a6  |................|
00000200  0c 00 e0 00 a5 0c 00 e1  00 a5 0c 00 e1 00 b4 0c  |................|
00000210  00 e1 00 ba 0c 00 e1 00  bc 0c 00 e1 00 cc 0c 00  |................|
00000220  e3 00 cf 0c 00 e4 00 b4  0c 00 e5 00 a5 0c 00 e5  |................|
00000230  00 a9 0c 00 e5 00 b8 0c  00 e5 00 cc 0c 00 e6 00  |................|
00000240  ad 0c 00 e7 00 b5 0c 00  e8 00 cf 0c 00 e9 00 a5  |................|
00000250  0c 00 ea 00 a8 0c 00 ea  00 b1 0c 00 ea 00 d1 0c  |................|
00000260  00 eb 00 a7 0c 00 eb 00  aa 0c 00 eb 00 b5 0c 00  |................|
00000270  eb 00 cc 0c 00 eb 00 cf  0c 00 f8 00 a5 0c 00 f9  |................|
00000280  00 a7 0c 00 f9 00 cf 0c  00 fd 00 aa 0c 00 fe 00  |................|
00000290  b9 0c 01 0e 00 cf 0c 01  0f 00 a5 0c 01 10 00 a7  |................|
000002a0  0c 01 11 00 a7 0c 01 14  00 ab 0c 01 18 00 cf 01  |................|
000002b0  00 00 01 00 18 20 2f 65  74 63 2f 69 6e 69 74 2e  |..... /etc/init.|
000002c0  64 2f 70 6d 74 61 20 72  65 6c 6f 61 64 01 00 19  |d/pmta reload...|
000002d0  20 2f 65 74 63 2f 69 6e  69 74 2e 64 2f 70 6d 74  | /etc/init.d/pmt|
000002e0  61 20 72 65 73 74 61 72  74 01 00 07 24 70 5f 64  |a restart...$p_d|
000002f0  6b 69 6d 01 00 09 24 70  5f 64 6f 6d 61 69 6e 01  |kim...$p_domain.|
00000300  00 05 24 70 5f 69 70 01  00 07 24 70 5f 76 6d 74  |..$p_ip...$p_vmt|
00000310  61 01 00 03 28 29 49 01  00 03 28 29 4a 01 00 14  |a...()I...()J...|
00000320  28 29 4c 6a 61 76 61 2f  6c 61 6e 67 2f 53 74 72  |()Ljava/lang/Str|
00000330  69 6e 67 3b 01 00 16 28  29 4c 6f 72 67 2f 6a 73  |ing;...()Lorg/js|
00000340  6f 6e 2f 4a 53 4f 4e 41  72 72 61 79 3b 01 00 03  |on/JSONArray;...|
00000350  28 29 56 01 00 03 28 29  5a 01 00 16 28 49 29 4c  |()V...()Z...(I)L|
00000360  6a 61 76 61 2f 6c 61 6e  67 2f 49 6e 74 65 67 65  |java/lang/Intege|
00000370  72 3b 01 00 1c 28 49 29  4c 6a 61 76 61 2f 6c 61  |r;...(I)Ljava/la|
00000380  6e 67 2f 53 74 72 69 6e  67 42 75 69 6c 64 65 72  |ng/StringBuilder|
00000390  3b 01 00 18 28 49 29 4c  6f 72 67 2f 6a 73 6f 6e  |;...(I)Lorg/json|
000003a0  2f 4a 53 4f 4e 4f 62 6a  65 63 74 3b 01 00 04 28  |/JSONObject;...(|
000003b0  49 29 56 01 00 3d 28 49  4c 6f 72 67 2f 6a 73 6f  |I)V..=(ILorg/jso|
000003c0  6e 2f 4a 53 4f 4e 41 72  72 61 79 3b 49 4c 6a 61  |n/JSONArray;ILja|
000003d0  76 61 2f 6c 61 6e 67 2f  53 74 72 69 6e 67 3b 4c  |va/lang/String;L|
000003e0  6a 61 76 61 2f 6c 61 6e  67 2f 53 74 72 69 6e 67  |java/lang/String|
000003f0  3b 29 56 01 00 04 28 4a  29 56 01 00 4a 28 4c 6a  |;)V...(J)V..J(Lj|
00000400  61 76 61 2f 6c 61 6e 67  2f 43 6c 61 73 73 3b 4c  |ava/lang/Class;L|
00000410  6a 61 76 61 2f 6c 61 6e  67 2f 53 74 72 69 6e 67  |java/lang/String|
00000420  3b 5b 4c 6a 61 76 61 2f  6c 61 6e 67 2f 4f 62 6a  |;[Ljava/lang/Obj|
00000430  65 63 74 3b 29 4c 6a 61  76 61 2f 6c 61 6e 67 2f  |ect;)Ljava/lang/|
00000440  4f 62 6a 65 63 74 3b 01  00 2d 28 4c 6a 61 76 61  |Object;..-(Ljava|
00000450  2f 6c 61 6e 67 2f 4f 62  6a 65 63 74 3b 29 4c 6a  |/lang/Object;)Lj|
00000460  61 76 61 2f 6c 61 6e 67  2f 53 74 72 69 6e 67 42  |ava/lang/StringB|
00000470  75 69 6c 64 65 72 3b 01  00 15 28 4c 6a 61 76 61  |uilder;...(Ljava|
00000480  2f 6c 61 6e 67 2f 4f 62  6a 65 63 74 3b 29 56 01  |/lang/Object;)V.|
00000490  00 15 28 4c 6a 61 76 61  2f 6c 61 6e 67 2f 4f 62  |..(Ljava/lang/Ob|
000004a0  6a 65 63 74 3b 29 5a 01  00 26 28 4c 6a 61 76 61  |ject;)Z..&(Ljava|
000004b0  2f 6c 61 6e 67 2f 53 74  72 69 6e 67 3b 29 4c 6a  |/lang/String;)Lj|
000004c0  61 76 61 2f 6c 61 6e 67  2f 53 74 72 69 6e 67 3b  |ava/lang/String;|
000004d0  01 00 2d 28 4c 6a 61 76  61 2f 6c 61 6e 67 2f 53  |..-(Ljava/lang/S|
000004e0  74 72 69 6e 67 3b 29 4c  6a 61 76 61 2f 6c 61 6e  |tring;)Ljava/lan|
000004f0  67 2f 53 74 72 69 6e 67  42 75 69 6c 64 65 72 3b  |g/StringBuilder;|
00000500  01 00 15 28 4c 6a 61 76  61 2f 6c 61 6e 67 2f 53  |...(Ljava/lang/S|
00000510  74 72 69 6e 67 3b 29 56  01 00 27 28 4c 6a 61 76  |tring;)V..'(Ljav|
00000520  61 2f 6c 61 6e 67 2f 53  74 72 69 6e 67 3b 4c 6a  |a/lang/String;Lj|
00000530  61 76 61 2f 6c 61 6e 67  2f 53 74 72 69 6e 67 3b  |ava/lang/String;|
00000540  29 5a 01 00 4a 28 4c 6a  61 76 61 2f 6c 61 6e 67  |)Z..J(Ljava/lang|
00000550  2f 53 74 72 69 6e 67 3b  4c 6a 61 76 61 2f 6c 61  |/String;Ljava/la|
00000560  6e 67 2f 53 74 72 69 6e  67 3b 4c 6a 61 76 61 2f  |ng/String;Ljava/|
00000570  6c 61 6e 67 2f 53 74 72  69 6e 67 3b 29 4c 6a 61  |lang/String;)Lja|
00000580  76 61 2f 6c 61 6e 67 2f  53 74 72 69 6e 67 3b 01  |va/lang/String;.|
00000590  00 18 28 4c 6a 61 76 61  2f 6c 61 6e 67 2f 54 68  |..(Ljava/lang/Th|
000005a0  72 6f 77 61 62 6c 65 3b  29 56 01 00 17 28 4c 6f  |rowable;)V...(Lo|
000005b0  72 67 2f 6a 73 6f 6e 2f  4a 53 4f 4e 41 72 72 61  |rg/json/JSONArra|
000005c0  79 3b 29 56 01 00 39 28  4c 74 65 63 68 2f 69 72  |y;)V..9(Ltech/ir|
000005d0  65 73 70 6f 6e 73 65 2f  63 61 73 65 2f 69 66 2f  |esponse/case/if/|
000005e0  74 68 72 6f 77 3b 29 4c  74 65 63 68 2f 69 72 65  |throw;)Ltech/ire|
000005f0  73 70 6f 6e 73 65 2f 77  68 69 6c 65 2f 69 66 3b  |sponse/while/if;|
00000600  01 00 01 29 01 00 09 2c  20 61 63 74 69 6f 6e 3d  |...)..., action=|
00000610  01 00 08 2c 20 69 73 70  49 64 3d 01 00 15 2c 20  |..., ispId=..., |
00000620  76 6d 74 61 43 6f 6e 66  69 67 54 65 6d 70 6c 61  |vmtaConfigTempla|
00000630  74 65 3d 01 00 0b 2c 20  76 6d 74 61 73 4d 61 70  |te=..., vmtasMap|
00000640  3d 01 00 05 2e 63 6f 6e  66 01 00 16 2e 63 6f 6e  |=....conf....con|
00000650  66 20 2f 65 74 63 2f 70  6d 74 61 2f 76 6d 74 61  |f /etc/pmta/vmta|
00000660  73 2f 01 00 01 2f 01 00  10 2f 65 74 63 2f 70 6d  |s/.../.../etc/pm|
00000670  74 61 2f 76 6d 74 61 73  2f 01 00 06 2f 68 6f 6d  |ta/vmtas/.../hom|
00000680  65 2f 01 00 06 3c 69 6e  69 74 3e 01 00 04 43 6f  |e/...<init>...Co|
00000690  64 65 01 00 22 43 6f 75  6c 64 20 6e 6f 74 20 63  |de.."Could not c|
000006a0  6f 6e 6e 65 63 74 20 74  6f 20 74 68 69 73 20 73  |onnect to this s|
000006b0  65 72 76 65 72 20 21 01  00 06 43 75 73 74 6f 6d  |erver !...Custom|
000006c0  01 00 07 44 65 66 61 75  6c 74 01 00 01 49 01 00  |...Default...I..|
000006d0  1f 49 6e 64 69 76 69 64  75 61 6c 56 6d 74 61 55  |.IndividualVmtaU|
000006e0  70 64 61 74 65 72 28 73  65 72 76 65 72 49 64 3d  |pdater(serverId=|
000006f0  01 00 22 4c 6a 61 76 61  2f 62 65 61 6e 73 2f 43  |.."Ljava/beans/C|
00000700  6f 6e 73 74 72 75 63 74  6f 72 50 72 6f 70 65 72  |onstructorProper|
00000710  74 69 65 73 3b 01 00 12  4c 6a 61 76 61 2f 6c 61  |ties;...Ljava/la|
00000720  6e 67 2f 53 74 72 69 6e  67 3b 01 00 0f 4c 6a 61  |ng/String;...Lja|
00000730  76 61 2f 73 71 6c 2f 44  61 74 65 3b 01 00 14 4c  |va/sql/Date;...L|
00000740  6f 72 67 2f 6a 73 6f 6e  2f 4a 53 4f 4e 41 72 72  |org/json/JSONArr|
00000750  61 79 3b 01 00 19 52 75  6e 74 69 6d 65 56 69 73  |ay;...RuntimeVis|
00000760  69 62 6c 65 41 6e 6e 6f  74 61 74 69 6f 6e 73 01  |ibleAnnotations.|
00000770  00 12 53 65 72 76 65 72  20 6e 6f 74 20 66 6f 75  |..Server not fou|
00000780  6e 64 20 21 01 00 0d 53  74 61 63 6b 4d 61 70 54  |nd !...StackMapT|
00000790  61 62 6c 65 01 00 19 56  6d 74 61 73 20 6d 61 70  |able...Vmtas map|
000007a0  70 69 6e 67 20 6e 6f 74  20 66 6f 75 6e 64 20 21  |ping not found !|
000007b0  01 00 01 5f 01 00 06 61  63 74 69 6f 6e 01 00 06  |..._...action...|
000007c0  61 70 70 65 6e 64 01 00  07 62 6f 6f 6c 65 61 6e  |append...boolean|
000007d0  01 00 05 62 72 65 61 6b  01 00 04 62 79 74 65 01  |...break...byte.|
000007e0  00 04 63 61 73 65 01 00  05 63 61 74 63 68 01 00  |..case...catch..|
000007f0  04 63 68 61 72 01 00 11  63 75 72 72 65 6e 74 54  |.char...currentT|
00000800  69 6d 65 4d 69 6c 6c 69  73 01 00 07 64 65 66 61  |imeMillis...defa|
00000810  75 6c 74 01 00 02 64 6f  01 00 06 64 6f 6d 61 69  |ult...do...domai|
00000820  6e 01 00 04 65 6c 73 65  01 00 06 65 71 75 61 6c  |n...else...equal|
00000830  73 01 00 03 66 6f 72 01  00 0d 67 65 74 4a 53 4f  |s...for...getJSO|
00000840  4e 4f 62 6a 65 63 74 01  00 09 67 65 74 53 74 72  |NObject...getStr|
00000850  69 6e 67 01 00 04 67 6f  74 6f 01 00 08 68 61 73  |ing...goto...has|
00000860  68 43 6f 64 65 01 00 02  69 66 01 00 03 69 6e 74  |hCode...if...int|
00000870  01 00 35 69 70 20 3d 20  3f 20 41 4e 44 20 69 73  |..5ip = ? AND is|
00000880  70 5f 69 64 20 3d 20 3f  20 41 4e 44 20 74 79 70  |p_id = ? AND typ|
00000890  65 20 3d 20 3f 20 41 4e  44 20 63 72 65 61 74 65  |e = ? AND create|
000008a0  64 5f 62 79 20 3d 20 3f  01 00 13 69 70 20 3d 20  |d_by = ?...ip = |
000008b0  3f 20 41 4e 44 20 74 79  70 65 20 3d 20 3f 01 00  |? AND type = ?..|
000008c0  05 69 73 70 49 64 01 00  13 6a 61 76 61 2f 6c 61  |.ispId...java/la|
000008d0  6e 67 2f 45 78 63 65 70  74 69 6f 6e 01 00 11 6a  |ng/Exception...j|
000008e0  61 76 61 2f 6c 61 6e 67  2f 49 6e 74 65 67 65 72  |ava/lang/Integer|
000008f0  01 00 10 6a 61 76 61 2f  6c 61 6e 67 2f 4f 62 6a  |...java/lang/Obj|
00000900  65 63 74 01 00 10 6a 61  76 61 2f 6c 61 6e 67 2f  |ect...java/lang/|
00000910  53 74 72 69 6e 67 01 00  17 6a 61 76 61 2f 6c 61  |String...java/la|
00000920  6e 67 2f 53 74 72 69 6e  67 42 75 69 6c 64 65 72  |ng/StringBuilder|
00000930  01 00 10 6a 61 76 61 2f  6c 61 6e 67 2f 53 79 73  |...java/lang/Sys|
00000940  74 65 6d 01 00 10 6a 61  76 61 2f 6c 61 6e 67 2f  |tem...java/lang/|
00000950  54 68 72 65 61 64 01 00  13 6a 61 76 61 2f 6c 61  |Thread...java/la|
00000960  6e 67 2f 54 68 72 6f 77  61 62 6c 65 01 00 0d 6a  |ng/Throwable...j|
00000970  61 76 61 2f 73 71 6c 2f  44 61 74 65 01 00 06 6c  |ava/sql/Date...l|
00000980  65 6e 67 74 68 01 00 03  6e 65 77 01 00 23 6f 72  |ength...new..#or|
00000990  67 2f 61 70 61 63 68 65  2f 63 6f 6d 6d 6f 6e 73  |g/apache/commons|
000009a0  2f 6c 61 6e 67 2f 53 74  72 69 6e 67 55 74 69 6c  |/lang/StringUtil|
000009b0  73 01 00 12 6f 72 67 2f  6a 73 6f 6e 2f 4a 53 4f  |s...org/json/JSO|
000009c0  4e 41 72 72 61 79 01 00  13 6f 72 67 2f 6a 73 6f  |NArray...org/jso|
000009d0  6e 2f 4a 53 4f 4e 4f 62  6a 65 63 74 01 00 09 70  |n/JSONObject...p|
000009e0  72 6f 74 65 63 74 65 64  01 00 07 72 65 70 6c 61  |rotected...repla|
000009f0  63 65 01 00 05 72 65 73  65 74 01 00 17 72 6d 20  |ce...reset...rm |
00000a00  2d 72 66 20 2f 65 74 63  2f 70 6d 74 61 2f 76 6d  |-rf /etc/pmta/vm|
00000a10  74 61 73 2f 01 00 04 72  6f 6f 74 01 00 03 72 75  |tas/...root...ru|
00000a20  6e 01 00 08 73 65 72 76  65 72 49 64 01 00 04 73  |n...serverId...s|
00000a30  75 64 6f 01 00 0e 73 75  64 6f 20 6d 76 20 2f 68  |udo...sudo mv /h|
00000a40  6f 6d 65 2f 01 00 17 74  65 63 68 2f 69 72 65 73  |ome/...tech/ires|
00000a50  70 6f 6e 73 65 2f 62 72  65 61 6b 2f 64 6f 01 00  |ponse/break/do..|
00000a60  1e 74 65 63 68 2f 69 72  65 73 70 6f 6e 73 65 2f  |.tech/iresponse/|
00000a70  63 61 73 65 2f 69 66 2f  65 78 74 65 6e 64 73 01  |case/if/extends.|
00000a80  00 1c 74 65 63 68 2f 69  72 65 73 70 6f 6e 73 65  |..tech/iresponse|
00000a90  2f 63 61 73 65 2f 69 66  2f 74 68 72 6f 77 01 00  |/case/if/throw..|
00000aa0  16 74 65 63 68 2f 69 72  65 73 70 6f 6e 73 65 2f  |.tech/iresponse/|
00000ab0  63 68 61 72 2f 64 6f 01  00 1b 74 65 63 68 2f 69  |char/do...tech/i|
00000ac0  72 65 73 70 6f 6e 73 65  2f 66 69 6e 61 6c 2f 64  |response/final/d|
00000ad0  6f 2f 74 72 79 01 00 16  74 65 63 68 2f 69 72 65  |o/try...tech/ire|
00000ae0  73 70 6f 6e 73 65 2f 74  68 69 73 2f 64 6f 01 00  |sponse/this/do..|
00000af0  17 74 65 63 68 2f 69 72  65 73 70 6f 6e 73 65 2f  |.tech/iresponse/|
00000b00  77 68 69 6c 65 2f 64 6f  01 00 17 74 65 63 68 2f  |while/do...tech/|
00000b10  69 72 65 73 70 6f 6e 73  65 2f 77 68 69 6c 65 2f  |iresponse/while/|
00000b20  69 66 01 00 04 74 68 69  73 01 00 06 74 68 72 6f  |if...this...thro|
00000b30  77 73 01 00 08 74 6f 53  74 72 69 6e 67 01 00 03  |ws...toString...|
00000b40  74 72 79 01 00 09 75 73  65 72 2d 70 61 73 73 01  |try...user-pass.|
00000b50  00 05 76 61 6c 75 65 01  00 07 76 61 6c 75 65 4f  |..value...valueO|
00000b60  66 01 00 07 76 6d 74 61  2d 69 70 01 00 12 76 6d  |f...vmta-ip...vm|
00000b70  74 61 43 6f 6e 66 69 67  54 65 6d 70 6c 61 74 65  |taConfigTemplate|
00000b80  01 00 08 76 6d 74 61 73  4d 61 70 01 00 04 76 6f  |...vmtasMap...vo|
00000b90  69 64 00 21 00 33 00 29  00 00 00 05 00 02 00 e1  |id.!.3.)........|
00000ba0  00 cc 00 00 00 02 00 ea  00 d1 00 00 00 02 00 e5  |................|
00000bb0  00 cc 00 00 00 02 00 eb  00 cf 00 00 00 02 00 f9  |................|
00000bc0  00 cf 00 00 00 10 00 01  01 02 00 a9 00 01 00 c8  |................|
00000bd0  00 00 04 8b 00 07 00 0d  00 00 03 31 01 4c 2a b4  |...........1.L*.|
00000be0  00 45 c6 00 0d 2a b4 00  45 b6 00 56 9a 00 0d bb  |.E...*..E..V....|
00000bf0  00 32 59 12 17 b7 00 60  bf bb 00 31 59 2a b4 00  |.2Y....`...1Y*..|
00000c00  43 b8 00 48 b7 00 5e 4d  12 1c 2a b4 00 46 b6 00  |C..H..^M..*..F..|
00000c10  4b 3e 2c b6 00 5f 99 00  0d bb 00 32 59 12 16 b7  |K>,.._.....2Y...|
00000c20  00 60 bf 2c b8 00 68 4c  2b c6 00 0a 2b b6 00 6b  |.`.,..hL+...+..k|
00000c30  9a 00 0d bb 00 32 59 12  12 b7 00 60 bf 12 1e 2c  |.....2Y....`...,|
00000c40  b4 00 42 b6 00 4b 99 00  08 12 01 a7 00 05 12 1f  |..B..K..........|
00000c50  3a 04 01 3a 05 b8 00 67  3a 06 bb 00 2b 59 b8 00  |:..:...g:...+Y..|
00000c60  51 b7 00 53 3a 07 03 36  08 15 08 2a b4 00 45 b6  |Q..S:..6...*..E.|
00000c70  00 56 a2 02 2b 2a b4 00  45 15 08 b6 00 55 3a 05  |.V..+*..E....U:.|
00000c80  19 05 c6 02 15 12 30 12  1a 07 bd 00 25 59 03 19  |......0.....%Y..|
00000c90  05 12 22 b6 00 57 53 59  04 2a b4 00 44 b8 00 48  |.."..WSY.*..D..H|
00000ca0  53 59 05 12 13 53 59 06  19 06 53 b8 00 5c c0 00  |SY...SY...S..\..|
00000cb0  30 3a 09 1d 99 00 3a 19  09 c6 01 de 19 09 b4 00  |0:....:.........|
00000cc0  3b 9e 01 d6 2b bb 00 27  59 b7 00 4c 12 1d b6 00  |;...+..'Y..L....|
00000cd0  4f 19 09 b4 00 39 b6 00  4f 12 0d b6 00 4f b6 00  |O....9..O....O..|
00000ce0  50 b6 00 6c 57 19 09 b6  00 5b 57 a7 01 ac 03 36  |P..lW....[W....6|
00000cf0  0a 19 09 c6 00 11 19 09  b4 00 3b 9e 00 09 04 36  |..........;....6|
00000d00  0a a7 00 6c 12 30 12 1b  05 bd 00 25 59 03 19 05  |...l.0.....%Y...|
00000d10  12 22 b6 00 57 53 59 04  12 14 53 b8 00 5c c0 00  |."..WSY...S..\..|
00000d20  30 3a 0b bb 00 30 59 19  0b b4 00 3b b8 00 48 b7  |0:...0Y....;..H.|
00000d30  00 59 3a 09 19 09 03 b5  00 3b 19 09 12 13 b5 00  |.Y:......;......|
00000d40  38 19 09 bb 00 27 59 b7  00 4c 19 09 b4 00 39 b6  |8....'Y..L....9.|
00000d50  00 4f 12 18 b6 00 4f 2a  b4 00 44 b6 00 4d b6 00  |.O....O*..D..M..|
00000d60  50 b5 00 39 19 09 2a b4  00 44 b5 00 3e 19 09 19  |P..9..*..D..>...|
00000d70  05 12 19 b6 00 57 b5 00  3c 2a b4 00 47 12 07 19  |.....W..<*..G...|
00000d80  09 b4 00 39 b8 00 54 3a  0b 19 0b 12 06 19 09 b4  |...9..T:........|
00000d90  00 3d b8 00 54 3a 0b 19  0b 12 05 19 05 12 19 b6  |.=..T:..........|
00000da0  00 57 b8 00 54 3a 0b 19  0b 12 04 12 01 b8 00 54  |.W..T:.........T|
00000db0  3a 0b 12 21 2c b4 00 41  b6 00 4b 99 00 7b 12 1e  |:..!,..A..K..{..|
00000dc0  2c b4 00 42 b6 00 4b 9a  00 6f 2b 19 0b bb 00 27  |,..B..K..o+....'|
00000dd0  59 b7 00 4c 12 11 b6 00  4f 2c b4 00 42 b6 00 4f  |Y..L....O,..B..O|
00000de0  12 0f b6 00 4f 19 09 b4  00 39 b6 00 4f 12 0d b6  |....O....9..O...|
00000df0  00 4f b6 00 50 b6 00 6a  57 2b bb 00 27 59 b7 00  |.O..P..jW+..'Y..|
00000e00  4c 12 20 b6 00 4f 2c b4  00 42 b6 00 4f 12 0f b6  |L. ..O,..B..O...|
00000e10  00 4f 19 09 b4 00 39 b6  00 4f 12 0e b6 00 4f 19  |.O....9..O....O.|
00000e20  09 b4 00 39 b6 00 4f 12  0d b6 00 4f b6 00 50 b6  |...9..O....O..P.|
00000e30  00 6c 57 a7 00 26 2b 19  0b bb 00 27 59 b7 00 4c  |.lW..&+....'Y..L|
00000e40  12 10 b6 00 4f 19 09 b4  00 39 b6 00 4f 12 0d b6  |....O....9..O...|
00000e50  00 4f b6 00 50 b6 00 6a  57 15 0a 99 00 1a 19 09  |.O..P..jW.......|
00000e60  19 06 b5 00 40 19 09 19  07 b5 00 3a 19 09 b6 00  |....@......:....|
00000e70  5a 57 a7 00 25 19 09 19  06 b5 00 3f 19 09 19 07  |ZW..%......?....|
00000e80  b5 00 37 19 09 19 06 b5  00 40 19 09 19 07 b5 00  |..7......@......|
00000e90  3a 19 09 b6 00 5d 57 84  08 01 a7 fd cf 2b bb 00  |:....]W......+..|
00000ea0  27 59 b7 00 4c 19 04 b6  00 4f 12 02 b6 00 4f b6  |'Y..L....O....O.|
00000eb0  00 50 b6 00 6c 57 2b bb  00 27 59 b7 00 4c 19 04  |.P..lW+..'Y..L..|
00000ec0  b6 00 4f 12 03 b6 00 4f  b6 00 50 b6 00 6c 57 2b  |..O....O..P..lW+|
00000ed0  c6 00 3c 2b b6 00 6b 99  00 35 2b b6 00 69 a7 00  |..<+..k..5+..i..|
00000ee0  2e 4d 2c b8 00 58 2b c6  00 25 2b b6 00 6b 99 00  |.M,..X+..%+..k..|
00000ef0  1e 2b b6 00 69 a7 00 17  3a 0c 2b c6 00 0e 2b b6  |.+..i...:.+...+.|
00000f00  00 6b 99 00 07 2b b6 00  69 19 0c bf b1 00 04 00  |.k...+..i.......|
00000f10  02 02 f3 03 05 00 23 00  02 02 f3 03 1c 00 00 03  |......#.........|
00000f20  05 03 0a 03 1c 00 00 03  1c 03 1e 03 1c 00 00 00  |................|
00000f30  01 00 d4 00 00 01 28 00  14 ff 00 13 00 02 00 05  |......(.........|
00000f40  00 00 ff 00 09 00 02 07  00 33 05 00 00 fd 00 29  |.........3.....)|
00000f50  07 00 31 01 ff 00 0f 00  02 00 07 00 36 00 00 ff  |..1.........6...|
00000f60  00 09 00 04 07 00 33 07  00 36 07 00 31 01 00 00  |......3..6..1...|
00000f70  10 41 07 00 26 ff 00 18  00 09 07 00 33 07 00 36  |.A..&.......3..6|
00000f80  07 00 31 01 07 00 26 00  07 00 26 07 00 2b 01 00  |..1...&...&..+..|
00000f90  00 ff 00 84 00 0a 07 00  33 07 00 36 07 00 31 01  |........3..6..1.|
00000fa0  07 00 26 07 00 2e 07 00  26 07 00 2b 01 07 00 30  |..&.....&..+...0|
00000fb0  00 00 ff 00 15 00 0b 07  00 33 07 00 36 07 00 31  |.........3..6..1|
00000fc0  01 07 00 26 07 00 2e 07  00 26 07 00 2b 01 00 01  |...&.....&..+...|
00000fd0  00 00 ff 00 68 00 0b 07  00 33 07 00 36 07 00 31  |....h....3..6..1|
00000fe0  01 07 00 26 07 00 2e 07  00 26 07 00 2b 01 07 00  |...&.....&..+...|
00000ff0  30 01 00 00 ff 00 c8 00  0c 07 00 33 07 00 36 07  |0..........3..6.|
00001000  00 31 01 07 00 26 00 07  00 26 07 00 2b 01 07 00  |.1...&...&..+...|
00001010  30 01 07 00 26 00 00 fa  00 22 fa 00 1b fa 00 21  |0...&....".....!|
00001020  ff 00 05 00 05 00 07 00  36 00 00 07 00 26 00 00  |........6....&..|
00001030  ff 00 43 00 02 00 07 00  36 00 01 07 00 23 56 07  |..C.....6....#V.|
00001040  00 2a ff 00 10 00 0d 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.*..............|
00001050  00 00 00 07 00 2a 00 00  ff 00 02 00 00 00 00 00  |.....*..........|
00001060  01 00 c7 00 af 00 02 00  c8 00 00 00 2c 00 02 00  |............,...|
00001070  06 00 00 00 20 2a b7 00  52 2a 1b b5 00 43 2a 2c  |.... *..R*...C*,|
00001080  b5 00 45 2a 1d b5 00 44  2a 19 04 b5 00 46 2a 19  |..E*...D*....F*.|
00001090  05 b5 00 47 b1 00 00 00  00 00 d2 00 00 00 1a 00  |...G............|
000010a0  01 00 ce 00 01 01 13 5b  00 05 73 01 03 73 01 17  |.......[..s..s..|
000010b0  73 00 ee 73 00 d7 73 01  16 00 01 00 e4 00 b4 00  |s..s..s.........|
000010c0  01 00 c8 00 00 01 2a 00  02 00 09 00 00 00 a7 2b  |......*........+|
000010d0  2a a6 00 05 04 ac 2b c1  00 33 9a 00 05 03 ac 2b  |*.....+..3.....+|
000010e0  c0 00 33 4d 2c 2a b6 00  62 9a 00 05 03 ac 2a b6  |..3M,*..b.....*.|
000010f0  00 61 2c b6 00 61 9f 00  05 03 ac 2a b6 00 64 4e  |.a,..a.....*..dN|
00001100  2c b6 00 64 3a 04 2d c7  00 0b 19 04 c6 00 11 a7  |,..d:.-.........|
00001110  00 0c 2d 19 04 b6 00 49  9a 00 05 03 ac 2a b6 00  |..-....I.....*..|
00001120  63 2c b6 00 63 9f 00 05  03 ac 2a b6 00 65 3a 05  |c,..c.....*..e:.|
00001130  2c b6 00 65 3a 06 19 05  c7 00 0b 19 06 c6 00 12  |,..e:...........|
00001140  a7 00 0d 19 05 19 06 b6  00 49 9a 00 05 03 ac 2a  |.........I.....*|
00001150  b6 00 66 3a 07 2c b6 00  66 3a 08 19 07 c7 00 0b  |..f:.,..f:......|
00001160  19 08 c6 00 12 a7 00 0d  19 07 19 08 b6 00 49 9a  |..............I.|
00001170  00 05 03 ac 04 ac 00 00  00 01 00 d4 00 00 00 71  |...............q|
00001180  00 0e 07 08 ff 00 0e 00  03 07 00 33 00 07 00 33  |...........3...3|
00001190  00 00 0c fd 00 16 07 00  2d 07 00 2d ff 00 08 00  |........-..-....|
000011a0  00 00 00 fe 00 01 07 00  33 00 07 00 33 0c ff 00  |........3...3...|
000011b0  18 00 07 07 00 33 00 07  00 33 00 00 07 00 26 07  |.....3...3....&.|
000011c0  00 26 00 00 ff 00 09 00  00 00 00 fe 00 01 07 00  |.&..............|
000011d0  33 00 07 00 33 ff 00 18  00 09 00 00 00 00 00 00  |3...3...........|
000011e0  00 07 00 26 07 00 26 00  00 ff 00 09 00 00 00 00  |...&..&.........|
000011f0  01 00 04 00 e1 00 b4 00  01 00 c8 00 00 00 11 00  |................|
00001200  01 00 02 00 00 00 05 2b  c1 00 33 ac 00 00 00 00  |.......+..3.....|
00001210  00 01 00 e9 00 a5 00 01  00 c8 00 00 00 cf 00 02  |................|
00001220  00 06 00 00 00 69 10 3b  3c 04 3d 1c 10 3b 68 2a  |.....i.;<.=..;h*|
00001230  b6 00 61 60 3d 2a b6 00  64 4e 1c 10 3b 68 2d c7  |..a`=*..dN..;h-.|
00001240  00 08 10 2b a7 00 07 2d  b6 00 4a 60 3d 1c 10 3b  |...+...-..J`=..;|
00001250  68 2a b6 00 63 60 3d 2a  b6 00 65 3a 04 1c 10 3b  |h*..c`=*..e:...;|
00001260  68 19 04 c7 00 08 10 2b  a7 00 08 19 04 b6 00 4a  |h......+.......J|
00001270  60 3d 2a b6 00 66 3a 05  1c 10 3b 68 19 05 c7 00  |`=*..f:...;h....|
00001280  08 10 2b a7 00 08 19 05  b6 00 4a 60 3d 1c ac 00  |..+.......J`=...|
00001290  00 00 01 00 d4 00 00 00  54 00 06 ff 00 21 00 04  |........T....!..|
000012a0  07 00 33 00 00 07 00 2d  00 01 01 ff 00 03 00 01  |..3....-........|
000012b0  07 00 33 00 02 01 01 ff  00 1f 00 05 07 00 33 00  |..3...........3.|
000012c0  00 00 07 00 26 00 01 01  ff 00 04 00 01 07 00 33  |....&..........3|
000012d0  00 02 01 01 ff 00 15 00  06 00 00 00 00 00 07 00  |................|
000012e0  26 00 01 01 ff 00 04 00  00 00 02 01 01 00 01 00  |&...............|
000012f0  e1 00 a5 00 01 00 c8 00  00 00 11 00 01 00 01 00  |................|
00001300  00 00 05 2a b4 00 43 ac  00 00 00 00 00 01 00 ea  |...*..C.........|
00001310  00 a8 00 01 00 c8 00 00  00 11 00 01 00 01 00 00  |................|
00001320  00 05 2a b4 00 45 b0 00  00 00 00 00 01 00 e5 00  |..*..E..........|
00001330  a5 00 01 00 c8 00 00 00  11 00 01 00 01 00 00 00  |................|
00001340  05 2a b4 00 44 ac 00 00  00 00 00 01 00 eb 00 a7  |.*..D...........|
00001350  00 01 00 c8 00 00 00 11  00 01 00 01 00 00 00 05  |................|
00001360  2a b4 00 46 b0 00 00 00  00 00 01 00 f9 00 a7 00  |*..F............|
00001370  01 00 c8 00 00 00 11 00  01 00 01 00 00 00 05 2a  |...............*|
00001380  b4 00 47 b0 00 00 00 00  00 01 00 e1 00 ae 00 01  |..G.............|
00001390  00 c8 00 00 00 12 00 02  00 02 00 00 00 06 2a 1b  |..............*.|
000013a0  b5 00 43 b1 00 00 00 00  00 01 00 e1 00 bb 00 01  |..C.............|
000013b0  00 c8 00 00 00 12 00 02  00 02 00 00 00 06 2a 2b  |..............*+|
000013c0  b5 00 45 b1 00 00 00 00  00 01 00 ea 00 ae 00 01  |..E.............|
000013d0  00 c8 00 00 00 12 00 02  00 02 00 00 00 06 2a 1b  |..............*.|
000013e0  b5 00 44 b1 00 00 00 00  00 01 00 e1 00 b7 00 01  |..D.............|
000013f0  00 c8 00 00 00 12 00 02  00 02 00 00 00 06 2a 2b  |..............*+|
00001400  b5 00 46 b1 00 00 00 00  00 01 00 ea 00 b7 00 01  |..F.............|
00001410  00 c8 00 00 00 12 00 02  00 02 00 00 00 06 2a 2b  |..............*+|
00001420  b5 00 47 b1 00 00 00 00  00 01 01 10 00 a7 00 01  |..G.............|
00001430  00 c8 00 00 00 58 00 02  00 01 00 00 00 4c bb 00  |.....X.......L..|
00001440  27 59 b7 00 4c 12 15 b6  00 4f 2a b6 00 61 b6 00  |'Y..L....O*..a..|
00001450  4d 12 0c b6 00 4f 2a b6  00 64 b6 00 4e 12 0a b6  |M....O*..d..N...|
00001460  00 4f 2a b6 00 63 b6 00  4d 12 09 b6 00 4f 2a b6  |.O*..c..M....O*.|
00001470  00 65 b6 00 4f 12 0b b6  00 4f 2a b6 00 66 b6 00  |.e..O....O*..f..|
00001480  4f 12 08 b6 00 4f b6 00  50 b0 00 00 00 00 00 00  |O....O..P.......|
00001490
```

Comment: I can not reproduce. If I copy your snippet 1:1, it does not compile on my end (javac 15). Voting to close as not reproducible. Could you share at least the original class file that you decompiled?

Comment: Evidently the project decompiles into uncompilable code.

Comment: @Zabuzard It's a project with hundreds of classes, the code above is just a small part of one single class, the class by itself is irrelevant to the problem and won't help you understand anything,

Comment: You'd have to examine the `.class` file to see what it contains.  Where does the decompiler get the variable names from?  Clearly the class file has been massaged to replace all the member names with semantically invalid tokens to prevent decompilation.

Comment: @khelwood Is this some sort of compiler that achieves this? Can-you please provide me with more information on this? I'd like to read some more.

Comment: @SoufianeTouil Just because you think the `.class` file would be irrelevant, doesnt mean it actually is irrelevant. Please show it. We have to see why your decompiler thinks that those names would be appropriate. We can not really help you with the information you gave so far.

Comment: @JimGarrison Usually, when I decompile jar files, I get the original variables names & never wondered where it came from, but this one is special, so I have no idea where the decompiler got the variable name from.

Comment: Suggestion: find the smallest class file in your project, run it through the decompiler, and post the entire result. Then add to that a hex dump of the class file in "canonical" format (i.e. `hexdump -C some.class` or equivalent).

Comment: @Zabuzard My apologies, i figured you were requesting the decompiled .java, not the .class, i'm adding It in a moment.

Comment: @JimGarrison Added both the java & hexdump of the smallest class.

Comment: Thanks, now the question contains everything relevant to answer and reproduce it. The hexdump shows it clearly. Upvoted and retracting my close vote.

Comment: You might find [Bytecode features not available in the Java language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827363/bytecode-features-not-available-in-the-java-language) interesting to read. It also explains this, see section **Use identifiers that are not normally considered legal**.

Comment: Thank you @Zabuzard! I really appreciate It.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While reserved words may not occur in Java source code, they are permitted in compiled Java code. Some code obfuscation tools can make use of this to make decompiling harder. For instance, ProGuard provides the following option:

> `-obfuscationdictionary filename`
>
> Specifies a text file from which all valid words are used as obfuscated field and method names. By default, short names like 'a', 'b', etc. are used as obfuscated names. With an obfuscation dictionary, you can specify a list of reserved key words, or identifiers with foreign characters, for instance. White space, punctuation characters, duplicate words, and comments after a# sign are ignored. Note that an obfuscation dictionary hardly improves the obfuscation. Decent compilers can automatically replace them, and the effect can fairly simply be undone by obfuscating again with simpler names. The most useful application is specifying strings that are typically already present in class files (such as 'Code'), thus reducing the class file sizes just a little bit more. Only applicable when obfuscating.

So if you feed this a list with Java identifiers (such as [this one](https://github.com/facebookarchive/proguard/blob/master/examples/dictionaries/keywords.txt)) you end up with a class file that causes syntax errors if decompiled. Of course, you can simply rename the variables to fix these compilation errors (for instance by using ProGuard yourself before decompiling), so this is only a minor inconvenience.

Comment: Related, [Bytecode features not available in the Java language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827363/bytecode-features-not-available-in-the-java-language). It also explains this, see section **Use identifiers that are not normally considered legal**.

Comment: Look for example in the bytecode dump for the string `Ltech/iresponse/case/if/throw;` - this is VM-style naming syntax (look up a bit from there for `Ljava/lang/String;` - that's JVMese for `java.lang.String`. In other words, because that is literally the names as encoded in the bytecode itself, where that's perfectly fine. It is not possible to write a java file that, if passed through `javac`, would produce this class file. So, yeah, it's proguard or some such.