# Java same erasure compile time error

Tags: java

I have two methods in same class:

```
public static Set<Type A> valueOf (Set<Type B>)
{}

public static Set<Type A> valueOf (Set<Type B>)
{}
```

I am getting same erasure compile time error. How do I resolve this?

Comment: specify what the exact error is please

Comment: Your two methods above are identical -- this is clearly a mistake. Can you edit your message to fix it, please?

Comment: The question is - why you would want to define the same method twice? Which one should the compiler pick when executing? The solution is obviously to separate the two methods by semantics. See also:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998544/method-has-the-same-erasure-as-another-method-in-type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your methods are exactly the same. The compiler won't know which one to use.

Also, in case you somehow meant

```
public static Set<Type A> valueOf (Set<Type A>)
{}

public static Set<Type B> valueOf (Set<Type B>)
{}
```

Those two methods are also the same, the type identifiers (`A` and `B`) get erased by the compiler, so they again end up having the same signature.

Answer (score 1):

To undestand what's going on, substitute each `<GenericSomething>` with `Object` since that is what the compiler sees - this is what's known as [type erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). Simply put, your both methods have the same signature, namely

```
public static Set<Object> valueOf (Set<Object>)
{}
```