# Method overloading not working with different parameters

Tags: java, generics, overloading

Why isn't this allowed and treated as same signature?

```
public Object myMethod(Map<String, String[]> values) {
   return this;
}

public Object myMethod(Map<String, String> values) {
   return this;
}
```

Comment: @DuncanJones - I see now, but really couldn't find that question. No idea what erasure was...

Comment: Worry not - duplicates are easier to find once the answer is known.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The urban myth answer is:

> Because [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html) causes the generics information to be lost. At runtime, those methods appear identical.
>
> `Map<X, Y>` becomes just `Map`.

However, the actual answer appears to be more complex. See this [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8467804/474189) from a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998544/method-has-the-same-erasure-as-another-method-in-type). The compiler is actually quite capable of selecting the correct overloaded method given the supplied arguments, however the requirement to support legacy non-generics-aware code has forced the `javac` developers to forbid it.

Comment: But overloading is done at compile time.

Comment: @artbristol You are quite correct actually. Having read in more detail the answers in the duplicate I linked, it is apparently a language syntax restriction. Sadly I can't delete this answer now that it's accepted, but I'll include a link to the other answer in the meantime.

Answer (score 6):

This is because of [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). Type Erasure removes most of the generics information at compile time. So above code after compilation would be

```
public Object myMethod(Map values) {
   return this;
}

public Object myMethod(Map values) {
   return this;
}
```

So both the methods are identical at runtime.