# Invoking Java Generic Methods

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure, generic-method

I am studying Java generic feature and I am not sure how to explain the third line in the following `main` method:

```
public class Example4 {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Util.<String>compare("a", "b"));
        System.out.println(Util.<String>compare(new String(""), new Long(1)));
        System.out.println(Util.compare(new String(""), new Long(1)));
    }
}

class Util {
    public static <T> boolean compare(T t1, T t2) {
        return t1.equals(t2);
    }
}
```

The first line compiles, runs, and returns (as expected) `false`.

The second line does not compile as expected, because I am explicitely mixing `String` and `Long`.

The third line compiles, runs, and return false but I am not sure to understand how it happens to work: does the compiler/JVM instantiates the parameter type `T` as `Object`? (Also, would there be a way to obtain this declared type of `T` are runtime?)

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer seems to go beyond @Telthien and @newacct' answers. I was curious to "see" for myself the difference between:

```
System.out.println(Util.<String>compare("a", "b"));
```

with explicity typing, and:

```
System.out.println(Util.compare(new String(""), new Long(1)));
```

with implicit typing.

I performed several experiments, using variations on these two previous lines. These experiments show that, short of using the [anonymous/local class trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901164/get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection/15999255#15999255), the compiler does check the types during compilation but the generated bytecodes only refer to `Object`, even in the case of the first line.

The following piece of code shows that typecasts can be performed safely all the way to `Object` even in the case of the explicity type argument `<String>`.

```
public final class Example44 {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Util44<String>().compare("a", "b"));
        System.out.println(new Util44().compare(new String(""), new Long(1)));
    }
}

final class Util44<T> {
    private T aT;
    public boolean compare(T t1, T t2) {
        System.out.println(this.aT);
        // I was expecting the second and third assignments to fail
        // with the first invocation because T is explicitly a String
        // and then to work with the second invocation because I use
        // a raw type and the compiler must infer a common type for T.
        // Actually, all these assignments succeed with both invocation. 
        this.aT = (T) new String("z");
        this.aT = (T) new Long(0);
        this.aT = (T) new Object();
        return t1.equals(t2);
    }
}
```

The bytecodes of the `main` method look like:

```
  // Method descriptor #15 ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
  // Stack: 7, Locals: 1
  public static void main(java.lang.String[] args);
     0  getstatic java.lang.System.out : java.io.PrintStream [16]
     3  new ca.polymtl.ptidej.generics.java.Util44 [22]
     6  dup
     7  invokespecial ca.polymtl.ptidej.generics.java.Util44() [24]
    10  ldc <String "a"> [25]
    12  ldc <String "b"> [27]
    14  invokevirtual ca.polymtl.ptidej.generics.java.Util44.compare(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object) : boolean [29]
    17  invokevirtual java.io.PrintStream.println(boolean) : void [33]
    20  getstatic java.lang.System.out : java.io.PrintStream [16]
    23  new ca.polymtl.ptidej.generics.java.Util44 [22]
    26  dup
    27  invokespecial ca.polymtl.ptidej.generics.java.Util44() [24]
    30  new java.lang.String [39]
    33  dup
    34  ldc <String ""> [41]
    36  invokespecial java.lang.String(java.lang.String) [43]
    39  new java.lang.Long [46]
    42  dup
    43  lconst_1
    44  invokespecial java.lang.Long(long) [48]
    47  invokevirtual ca.polymtl.ptidej.generics.java.Util44.compare(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object) : boolean [29]
    50  invokevirtual java.io.PrintStream.println(boolean) : void [33]
    53  return
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 24]
        [pc: 20, line: 25]
        [pc: 53, line: 26]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 54] local: args index: 0 type: java.lang.String[]
```

It actually makes sense that all the calls are always to methods with `Object` as formal parameter types, as explained [in another question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998544/method-has-the-same-erasure-as-another-method-in-type). To conlude, the compiler always uses `Object` for the generated bytecodes, not matter if there is an explicity type argument (first line) or an implicit type argument but that the objects could have a common superclass different from `Object`.

Comment: Just to note this here, even though you link to it; the phenomenon is called "type erasure".

Comment: Yeah.  Basically,  Java implements generics as behind-the-scenes typecasting.  For example, an `ArrayList<String>` internally considers every element to be an `Object`, but automatically casts it back to `String` when you use it.

Answer (score 21):

The shared inherited type of `String` and `Long` is `Object`.

When you run this function as `Util.<String>compare(` the compiler expects to find two string inputs, and gives an error when it doesn't. However, running it without `<String>` results in the use of the closest shared inherited type - in this case, `Object`.

Thus, when `compare` accepts `t1` and `t2`, they have been cast as `Object`, and the code runs fine.

To get the actual type at runtime you use the same technique that you would use with any other object: The `getClass()` which is inherited from the `Object` class.

Comment: Also for the second part(way to obtain declared type of T at runtime) search for "Reified Generics" on Google. Refer gafter.blogspot.com/2006/11/reified-generics-for-java.html

Comment: The getClass() method applied to, say, t1, will return String because it is the runtime type, won't it?

Comment: While doing more research, I stumbled upon this interesting Blog entry: [super type tokens](http://gafter.blogspot.kr/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html).

Comment: You can also use `instanceof`, but that's slower.  However, from within `compare` the strings have been anonymized -  the only way to read them is to read the class string and interpret it (at least as far as I know).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `Object` is a choice for `T` that will allow it to compile. Conceptually, the compiler *infers* a type for `T`. What it particularly infers doesn't matter -- as long as it can infer that *some type* will work for `T`, then it compiles. It doesn't matter what that inferred type is, since it has no effect on the compiled code.