# How to write a overloaded function which can accept List<Integer> or List<Double> in java?

Tags: java, overloading

I understand there is some backward compatibility issue, and it is not allowed by compiler.

[Method has the same erasure as another method in type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998544/method-has-the-same-erasure-as-another-method-in-type)

how do others achieve this? Is there any other solution than to define them with different function names?

Comment: Please describe what your use case is. Using separate method names might be the best way, but, for example, you might also be able to use `List<E extends Number>`.

Comment: i'm getting x and y coordinates as list of numbers, if it is double, i'll scale it to width or height, based on x or y.

Comment: @ChakradarRaju That's a horrible design. Such a subtle difference in behavior shouldn't depend on the overloading difference between integers and floats. Just give the two methods different names.

Answer (score 0):

this is because at bytecodelevel, the generic is removed and you have basically a list of objects.. resulting in two identical method-signatures.

but  you could use `Integer[]` and `Double[]` instead if it fits your requirements because these ARE different types.

Answer (score 0):

you can make them generic like List and at the time of instantiation just tell what you want to do. Either declare as List or as List.

Answer (score 0):

make a generic list like:-

```
List<> list= new ArrayList<>();
```

you can write any parameter like `T,V,B` or any other in the brackets and then later on on in the main you define the generic parameter either as `Integer` or as `Double`. Generally,`T` is used.

Read generics for better understanding.

Answer (score -3):

Probably you can take the parameter as List of Object. In the implemention, check the class type of the object passed and have a switch to process different for integer and double

Please accept/vote up, if this resolves your query

Comment: Try your own suggestion, and you'll see that it doesn't fit. Hint: a List<Double> is not a List<Object>. Second hint: the class of the argument will always be List.class.

Comment: Completely avoiding the generics system isn't the best way to resolve the issue, especially when the types involve share a close superclass (`Number`).

Comment: Sorry. Yes, I thought about this just after submitting the answer. Could not find a way to delete an answer after it gets posted.