# Static method overriding(?) with generics gives a clashes error

Tags: java, generics, static-methods

given:

```
static class ClassA {
    static <V> ClassA create( List<V> things ) {
        //do something with things
        return new ClassA();
    }
}

static class ClassB extends ClassA {
    //note: using <V> is fine, but <V extends Number> gives an error
    static <V extends Number> ClassB create(List<V> numbers) {
        //do something with numbers
        return new ClassB();
    }
}
```

I am getting the error:

> 'create(List)' in 'ClassB' clashes with 'create(List)' in 'ClassA'; both methods have same erasure, yet neither hides the other

Easy way around this problem is to just name the methods differently, but I want to better understand why this is a problem (and if there are workarounds).

From my understanding of static methods, the method to call is picked based on the static type of the object. so `ClassA foo = new ClassB(); foo.create(null);` would make a call to `ClassA.create(null)`. And of course, there shouldn't be a problem with picking the right method when using the class name directly: `ClassB.create` or `ClassA.create`.

My guess is that it would have a problem with `ClassB.create(new ArrayList<String>())`. Though at compile time, it would still be possible to determine that `ClassA.create` could (should(?)) be called.

Comment: Static methods cannot be overridden.

Comment: Which method should this call: `ClassB.create(new ArrayList<Integer>())`

Comment: @xiaofeng.li I am not trying to override them as such, otherwise i could use `<V> for ClassB` which compiles and works.

Comment: @shmosel `ClassB`'s create, mainly because of the explicit `ClassB`.

Comment: `ClassB` effectively declares both methods, since neither can hide the other.

Comment: the compiler puts a 'copy' of the method in `ClassB`? that doesn't sound right, private static fields used in `ClassA` would no longer be accessible by `ClassB` if that were the case

Comment: Perhaps this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998280/name-clash-compile-error-when-compiled-in-java-7-but-works-fine-in-java-5) can give you the answer.

Comment: I think the problem is that Java allows static methods to be accessed via an object and not just by the class name itself.  It's not recommended but it's allowed. `ClassB obj = new ClassB(); obj.create(new List() );` and the compiler can't decide which you mean.  Not sure but that's the only thing that comes to mind.

Comment: incase of `obj.create` it is chosen based on the static type of `obj`, which is why `ClassA obj = null; obj.create(null)` would not throw a NullPointerException.