# Multiple Bounded Generics in Java

Tags: java, generics

Am having  Class A ,Interfaces B,C . aA extends A,aB implements B,cC implements C.But if I try to use MultipleBounded Generics.It is showing compilation error using jdk 1.7.
Please help me to correct the errornous. [LINK FOR REFERENCE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)

```
public class MultipleBounds {
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
      D d1 = new D();
      d1.print(new bB()); // compilation Error
      d1.print(new cC()); // compilation Error
      d1.print(new aA()); // It works no Issues
    }
}

class A {
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("methodA");
    }
}

interface B {
    public void method();
}

interface C {
    public void method();
}

class aA extends A {
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("methodaA");
    }
}

class bB implements B {
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("methodbB");
    }
}

class cC implements C {
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("methodcC");
    }
}

class D<T extends A & B & C> 
{
    public void print(T t)
    {
        t.method();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using raw type `D` for invoking the method, all the generic information from the class is lost. And the method `print` will be replaced by it's erasure.

Now, the erasure of the type parameter `T` is the left-most bound it has, which is `A`. This is evident in [JLS §4.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6):

> The erasure of a type variable (§4.4) is the erasure of its leftmost bound.

So, what compiler sees is this:

```
class D {
    public void print(A t)
    {
        t.method();
    }  
}
```

That is why, it works for `A` and not for `B` and `C`. Lesson: [Avoid using raw types.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/1679863)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here: `D d1 = new D();`. You are using a raw type, therefore losing the generics information. And the type erasure of a type intersection `A & B & C` is [its first component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142467/generics-ambiguity-with-the-operator-and-order) (`A`). So your `d1` can only accepts `A`s.

For example, if you reorder it to `B & A & C`, you will only be able to pass `B`s.

Finally note that you would not be able to declare your `D` using generics because no class in your code is an `A` and a `B` and a `C`. You could create a `class ABC extends A implements B, C` and use `D<ABC> d = new D<>();`

Comment: But there is no difference of <T extends A> or <T extends B> or <T extends C>  .Becasue then what is the use of the multiple bounded.

Comment: @sunleo You'll see the difference, once you use parameterized type. You can't create a `D<aA>`, but you can create a `D<ABC>`.

Comment: @sunleo `T extends A & B` means that you expect a type that is an A _and_ a B. But you need to declare your `D` class with generics to see it. See my last paragraph.