# Why is this overloading wrong?

Tags: java, generics, overloading

I am new to Generics (Java). I was following the official Oracle docs and it's mentioned in there:

[image]

So, if that is the case, why **printList** fails but **add** doesn't?

[image]

Am I missing something from the core definitions of two? Pardon me, if this question is too stupid to ask or already is on stackoverflow. Atleast I couldn't find any answer.

Comment: Type erasure. There are no generics at run time so you cannot have two methods with the same signature.

Comment: Okay, I got that there are no generics at runtime but the error is at compile time, right? For compile time, it is correct?

Comment: @BoristheSpider This isn't necessitated by type erasure. This type information is, in fact, included in compiled classes. It was a choice by the language designers to ensure safe evolution between language versions. Read the [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998544/method-has-the-same-erasure-as-another-method-in-type) linked by Hypino.