# inheritance in java and generics

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I agree that without extending class B  the output is "1233" but why if extending class B with A the code doesn't compile ?

```
public class SomeClass {

    public static class A {

        public void f(int x){
            System.out.print("1");
        }

        public void f(Object x){
            System.out.print("2");
        }
    }

    public static class B // extends A {

        public <T> void f(T x){
             System.out.print("3");
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args){
        A a=new A();
        B b=new B();
        a.f(3);
        a.f("hello");
        b.f(3);
        b.f("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the error message tell you?

Answer (score 3):

The method signatures results in name clash, following two method signatures are having the problem of name clash as generic method is not actually overriding the former one. After [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) both will have the same signature.

```
public <T> void f(T x){...}
public void f(Object x){...}
```

Method which is declared in `B` is not overriding the method of `A` as method is said to be overridden if,

> [JLS 8.4.8.1. Overriding (by Instance Methods)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1)
>
> An instance method m<sub>C</sub> declared in or inherited by class C, overrides
>   from C another method m<sub>A</sub> declared in class A, iff all of the following
>   are true:
>
> - A is a superclass of C.
> - C does not inherit m<sub>A</sub>.
> - The signature of m<sub>C</sub> is a subsignature ([§8.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2)) of the signature of m<sub>A</sub>.
>     
>   **....**

Here following is valid and compiles fine,

```
public static class A {

    public <T> void f(T x) {
        System.out.print("3");
    }
}

public static class B extends A {

    @Override
    public void f(Object x) {
        System.out.print("2");
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it correct to say that: method can't  be overridden by generic method (in other words parent can be generic but not it's descendant)?

Comment: @tami Not exactly. Same signature as the base method is also valid and some other signatures are also valid in case of generic method.

Comment: "Same signature as the base method is also valid" , does it mean that to write "public <T> void f(T x)" in both classes ( A and B) will be correct? Is it also be an override if I put "public void f(int x)" (not only "public void f(Object x)")?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compile the above classes because of the type erasure problem.

The method that you have in your base class is generic and matches `f(Object x)` in your parent class. This will happen at compile time.

```
public void f(Object x){}
public <T> void f(T x){}
```

See [this Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) about Type Erasures.

---

However, you can keep `int` method and it will compile fine:

```
class A {
      public void f(int x){
         System.out.print("1");
      }
}

public class B extends A
{
      public <T> void f(T x){
         System.out.print("3");
      }
}
```

Comment: This is not true. Remove the method `f(int x)` and it still won't compile.

Answer (score 1):

Java generics uses type erasure. `javac` will have clash while resolving

```
public <T> void f(T x);
public void f(Object x);
```

Both are same with respect to compiler `javac`.

Adding another [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998544/method-has-the-same-erasure-as-another-method-in-type/8467804#8467804):

```
class Test{
   void add(Set<Integer> ii){}
   void add(Set<String> ss){}
}
```

`This limitation is part of the language syntax, not the Java runtime itself. Essentially, this rule is intended to avoid conflicts in legacy code that still uses raw types.`

Please refer to the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

A method can only be overridden in derived class if the argument list are exactly same as that of the overridden method and the return type should be the same or a subtype of the return type of overridden method (in parent class).

You can override following method

```
public <T> void f(T x) {
          System.out.print("3");
      }
```

You can find more information on [Overriding and Hiding Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)

Answer (score 0):

The Problem because of The method f(String) is ambiguous for the type B in SomeClass, you can fix it like this

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static class A {
        public void f(int x) {
            System.out.print("1");
        }

        public void f(Object x) {
            System.out.print("2");
        }
    }

    public static class B extends A {
        public void f(Object x) {
            System.out.print("3");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        a.f(3);
        a.f("hello");
        b.f(3);
        b.f("hello");
    }
}
```

And will work, hope that help.