# Overloading a method: both methods have same erasure

Tags: java, generics, jvm, javac

I have the following code and it doesn't work: the error `both methods have same erasure` appears.

```
public class Foo<V>  {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
    }

    public void Bar(V value)  {
    }

    public void Bar(Object value)  {
    } 
}
```

Also I have this code:

```
public class Foo<V>  {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
    }

    public void Bar(B value)  {
    }

    public void Bar(A value)  {
    }
}

class A  {
}

class B extends A  {
}
```

And this works. In the first case `V` is a child of `Object`, just like in the second case `B` is a child of `A`. Then why the first case results in error, while the second compiles successfully?

**EDIT**: What should I do to achieve method overloading, without raising an error?

Comment: Because [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) affects the first, but not the second.

Comment: [Type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). When the generic is erased, it changes from `Bar(V value)` to `Bar(Object value)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method has the same erasure as another method in type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998544/method-has-the-same-erasure-as-another-method-in-type)

Comment: *"`V` is a child of `Object`"*. No. `V` is a type parameter that can be any subclass of `Object`, but also `Object` itself. So as far as compiler is concerned, `V` could be an `Object` and hence there is no difference between the two methods.

Comment: The proposed duplicate gives the best explanation of why the rules are the way they are--it's for backward compatibility with raw generic types.  If it weren't for that, Java could have allowed this kind of syntax pretty easily, and only generated an error if you use it on a `Foo<Object>` but not on `Foo<AnythingElse>`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> What should I do to achieve method overloading, without raising an error?

Simple: don't try to overload the method with parameters with the same erasure.

A few options:

1. Just give the methods different names (i.e. don't try to use overloading)
2. Add further parameters to one of the overloads, to allow disambiguation (ideally only do this if you actually *need* those parameters; but there are examples in the Java API where there are junk parameters simply to avoid overloading issues).
3. Bound the type variable, as suggested by [@Kayaman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43442537/3788176):

   ```
   <V extends SomethingOtherThanObject>
   ```

Comment: I vote for #1... Overloading is a convenience. There's never any _need_ to provide method overloading (except perhaps some complex cases involving reflection to look up methods by name).

Comment: @ajb indeed. Languages like [go](https://golang.org/) simply don't allow overloading at all, demonstrating that it's entirely workable to avoid it.

Answer (score 7):

`V` isn't "a child of `Object`". `V` is an unbounded generic type that erases to `Object`, resulting in the error. If the generic type were bounded, such as `<V extends Comparable<V>>`, it would erase to `Comparable` and you wouldn't get the error.