# Generic Map Parameter java

Tags: java, generics

I am having a lot of methods of this type:

```
public static List<EduUsers> getDetails(Class c, Map<String, Integer> params) {
        List<EduUsers> details = null;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(c);
            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                cr.add(Restrictions.eq(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
            }
            details = cr.list();
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception asd) {
            log.debug(asd.getMessage());
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.commit();
            }
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return details;
    }
```

I am trying to have a generic Method for them and this is what I have written so far:

```
 public static <T> List<T> getDetails(Class<T> c, Class<T> b) {
        List<T> details = null;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(c);
            //am stuck on iteration of the map from Class T b
            details = cr.list();
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception asd) {
            log.debug(asd.getMessage());
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return details;
    }
```

How do I put up a generic Map onto the method?

**EDIT:  My Map values type can change I need to be able to put not just Integers but Strings as well and other types**

Comment: why have you changed Map to Class in method parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use generic map you should define your method to allow a **Map** with any type of object to pass in **Value** place of **Map**.

Your new method should look like this `getDetails(Class<T> c,Map<String,?> params)`

and Map Entry iterator should look like as below:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                cr.add(Restrictions.eq(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
 }
```

Comment: This does not work, had actually tried that. It returns `name clash: <T>getDetails(Class<T>,Map<String,?>) and getDetails(Class,Map<String,Integer>) have the same erasure`

Comment: @ErrorNotFoundException are you writing new method , without removing old method? if it is then it will give the error as you mentioned.,  check the link for more on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998544/method-has-the-same-erasure-as-another-method-in-type, you cannot make it is because Map<String,Integer> and generic Map<String,?> are same based on Map./

Comment: Oh, sorry, I had to remove the first Method which was clashing with the first one. My bad. This actually Worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just as easy as adding `Map<? extends Object, ? extends Object>`to your method's parameters list.

```
public static<T> List<T> getDetails(Class<T> c, Map<? extends Object, ? extends Object> params)
```

Another option would be adding two other parameter types:

```
private static <T, S, X> List<T> getDetails(Class<T> clazz, Map<S, X> map) {
    ...
    for (Map.Entry<S, X> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            cr.add(Restrictions.eq(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
     }
    ...
  }
```

The new parameter `Class<T> b` can be removed, since it doesn't been used anywhere.

Comment: See problem is My map value can change from Integer to other types.

Comment: Does this types have a super type ? If not, make Object as their upper bound. I've also updated my answer with a second option.